# Zend Framework 2 subdomain routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2, url-routing

I need to make a subdomain routing in ZF2 for these domains:

```
<?=$this->url('subdomain', array('subdomain' => 'sub'));?>
// sub.domain.ltd

<?=$this->url('subdomain/static/js', array('file' => 'jquery.js'));?>
// static.domain.ltd/js/jquery.js
```

How can I do this? Any ideas?

First base route is easy:

```
    'subdomain' => array(
        'type'    => 'hostname',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => ':subdomain.domain.ltd',
            'constraints' => array(
                'subdomain' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'subdomain'  => 'www',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(),
    ),
```

But what i have to write in child_routes to manage my task?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding of static assets in your application is another paragraph :)
You can use view helpers, for example [basepath](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.base-path.html) and you can set different layout for different subdomain..

This solution is possibile in your flow?

Comment: I don't need to use layouts, I just need to have an url. So I only need to have a correct route.